# why is my legend in ggplot2 in power bi backwards?

Tags: r, ggplot2, powerbi

so i am running the r visual in power bi desktop, i put in my data set and written the code, but the legend shows up all messed up, can some one point out what i am doing wrong?

below is the code

```
x = dataset$yearnum
y = dataset$oddmean_interv
# y is red color
a = dataset$odd_ul95
b = dataset$odd_ll95

z = dataset$oddmean_base
# z is blue color
c = dataset$odd_ul95_base
d = dataset$odd_ll95_base

#converts column to vector


library(ggplot2)

p = ggplot(dataset, aes(x=x)) + geom_line(aes(y=y, color="blue")) + geom_line(aes(y=z, color="red")) +
    ylim(0, 35) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=b, ymax=a), width=0.2, position=position_dodge(0.05)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=d, ymax=c), width=0.2, position=position_dodge(0.05)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("red", "blue")) +
  labs(x = "Year", y="Mean Overdose Per 100,000") 
  
print(p)
```

here is what it shows

[image]

i am trying to get the red line to say oddmean_interv and the blue line to say oddmean_base.

any help is appreciated

Comment: The order of the legend is not dependent on the definition in `scales` but on the order of the data. Because you have defined a geom for each color, I would assume, that you have to switch the `geom_line` calls

Comment: Also if you actually want to define the color use `I("blue")` in the aesthetics, or move the color definition out of the `aes()`

Comment: Try with using named vectors, i.e. `scale_colour_manual(values=c(red = "red", blue = "blue"), labels=c(red = "oddmean_interv", blue = "oddmean_base"))`